# Does GTA V activate on Steam?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

If I buy GTA V from, for example, Amazon, will it come with a Steam CD Key, or will this be a separate, non-Steam version of the game?

Comment: @tzhx why remove the link?

Comment: It served no purpose and made the question read poorly. Everyone knows what Amazon are.

Comment: I would hope that you already knew this answer, Gabe.

Comment: For reference, Amazon lists the DRM of any downloadable title near the top of the listing - next to the ESRB rating, below the title of the game, and above the star count.  In this case, it reads "Rockstar Games Social Club" - if it read "Steam" or "Steamworks" it would activate on Steam instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. GTAV is not a SteamWorks game. Retail copies do not activate to your Steam account.

Instead, they will be activated against a "Rockstar Social Club" account (as Steam copies also do).

Comment: So what do I lose out on going with a retail copy? Achievements and trading cards(lol) from Steam?

Comment: I don't think it has trading cards on Steam atm, but yes -- you would miss out on Steam achievements if they matter to you and trading cards if they eventually get introduced.